# Overlaying issue in heremap implementation

Tags: maps, here-maps-rest

I am not able to overlay the here map.
First time I can pass lat lang and it gets plotted.
on the same when I pass different latlang I see old and new plot at the same time. Need to solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding a new marker in the here map. Rather than doing that, try doing it this way:

1. Create a marker object with a latitude and longitude.
2. Use that marker object and just update the geo-coordinate with the updated latitude and longitude.